# How to counter number for each item when they have same category?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 let data = [
 {size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", index: 1},
 {size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", index: 2},
 {size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", index: 3},
 {size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", index: 4},
 {size: 267776, category: "CRSA", index: 5},:
 {size: 328704, category: "Arundel", index: 6}
 {size: 73216, category: "Arundel", index: 7}

 data.forEach((product, index) => {
       let count = 0;
       if (product.category !== lastCategory) {            
         rows.push(
            <ProductCategoryRow 
                                category={product.category}
                                key={product.category}/>
        );
    }
    rows.push(
        <ProductRow
            product={product}
            key={product.name} count={count}/>
    );
    lastCategory = product.category;

});
```

I want calculate count(number) which have same category. Number will increase if they fall into same category.  So that will pass through as props to component

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Output should be like: [
{size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", count: 1},
{size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", count: 1},
{size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", count: 2},
{size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", count: 1},
{size: 267776, category: "CRSA", count: 1},
{size: 328704, category: "Arundel", count: 1},
{size: 73216, category: "Arundel", count: 2}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 let dataArray = [
 {size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", index: 1},
 {size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", index: 2},
 {size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", index: 3},
 {size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", index: 4},
 {size: 267776, category: "CRSA", index: 5},
 {size: 328704, category: "Arundel", index: 6},
 {size: 73216, category: "Arundel", index: 7}
 ]

var d = dataArray.reduce(function (Objects, data, index) { 
  console.log(Objects)
  if (data.category in Objects) {
    Objects[data.category]++;
  }
  else {
    Objects[data.category] = 1;
  }
  dataArray[index].counts = Objects[data.category];
  return Objects;
}, {});

console.log(dataArray)
```

[working js fiddle](https://jsbin.com/zasibedexa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you so much @user9435027

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const counts = data.reduce((counts, product) => {
  counts[product.category] = (counts[product.category] || 0) + 1
  return counts
}, {})
// counts = {Arundel: 2, ...}
```

Than create your elements:

```
let rows = []
data.forEach(product => {
  rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category}>)
  rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} count={counts[product.categort]} />
})
```

Comment: I don''t need calculated size just need how many time every item having same category. Like [ {size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", count: 1}, {size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", count: 1}, {size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", count: 2}, {size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", count: 1}, {size: 267776, category: "CRSA", count: 1}, {size: 328704, category: "Arundel", count: 1}, {size: 73216, category: "Arundel", count: 2}]

Comment: Not the total count it should be like previous comment that i had commented

Comment: [ {size: 1180160, category: "Keswick", count: 1}, {size: 1059328, category: "HCOPA", count: 1}, {size: 30720, category: "HCOPA", count: 2}, {size: 493056, category: "Darhan Saluja", count: 1}, {size: 267776, category: "CRSA", count: 1}, {size: 328704, category: "Arundel", count: 1}, {size: 73216, category: "Arundel", count: 2}]